# Button.CharacterSpacing Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to increase the **characters spacing** in a **button** on Xamarin.Forms.

That's my code:

```
<Button Text="Click me" Clicked="btnOpen_Clicked" HorizontalOptions="End" x:Name="btnOpen" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White">
    <Button.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="Roboto-Medium" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="Roboto-Medium.ttf#Roboto" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Button.FontFamily>
</Button>
```

I found the property `<button.CharacterSpacing>` but I don't know how to apply it.

Is it possible to make this change directly from xaml or do I have to go another way?

Thank you

Comment: "I don't know how to apply it" - what have you tried?  The docs say it's a double.  Have you tried just applying some different values to see how it behaves?

Comment: @Jason not finding anything online, I tried to apply it in the same style as the font, but I found the error that the property does not support onplatform, or using the set property (`<Button.CharacterSpacing set="2"></Button.CharacterSpacing>` ), but in any case I found errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CharacterSpacing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#character-spacing) is a double property

```
<Button Text="Click me" Clicked="btnOpen_Clicked" CharacterSpacing="10"  ...
```

Comment: Okay, it works. My fault, I still have a basic level of xaml. Thank you and excuse me!